# Store Dynamic Property in Gremlin Vertex

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am working on moving a SQL Cosmos collection set over to a graph (our data works well with graphing) and I am having a problem.

I have one property on my vertex that is a dynamic object. It varies (even within the singular type of the vertex) and what I have done in the past is simply stick it in a dynamic field and shove it into cosmos.

I haven't been able to get that working with the Gremlin API (as it requires me to push a string value to a property and when I move it to and from JSON it ends up funky).

Is there some way that I am missing to get this working? Let me know if any samples would elucidate this questions.

Cheers